# Ruby C extension vs Spawn Exectuable via #system

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I have some Ruby code that interacts with a C application. Right now, it spawns the executable  using the [Kernel#system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) method each time it needs to pass data to the application. What are the advantages/disadvantages system-side with this approach versus creating a Ruby C extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Kernel#system

*Advantages*

Calling native code through `Kernel#system` is the **simplest** option to implement, and therefore the fastest to code. It's also **flexible** -- you can easily call not only C code, but executables of any other language: shell scripts, Python, what have you.

*Disadvantages*

Using `system` involves a relatively **large amount of overhead**: it forks your Ruby interpreter process, execs a subshell, invokes the C application, and then waits for the child process to exit. All of these are fairly costly in terms of time and system resources, especially if you're doing it in a tight loop.

### C extensions

*Advantages*

Interfacing with native code by writing a C extension gets you **blazing speed** and **low overhead**. It also gives you a great deal more flexibility in terms of sending data to and from C-land; with `system`, you need to be able to serialize the child application's inputs through command-line arguments (and you need to use either backticks or pipes to collect its output), but when you're writing an extension you can just **pass Ruby objects in and out**, which lets you construct a more natural API.

*Disadvantages*

C extensions are a lot **more work** to write, build, and distribute properly. Also, if you mess up in C-land, you'll often crash your interpreter instead of throwing an exception, which is **harder to debug**. Unless you're careful, you're also likely to bind yourself to the platform you're writing on, which **hurts portability**.

### Summary

Really, the best guidance is to start simple, and add the complexities of C extensions where it's actually measurably beneficial (read: after benchmarking).